# jquery popup won't position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery mobile popup appear when the user enters a text box. Several issues I can't figure out.

1. If I make the popup appear by clicking a button, it nicely slides in from the right, but slides in to the middle of the target text field, rather than the desired right side.
2. If I make it appear when the user enters the text field (gains focus), it no longer slides in from the right and it is in the wrong position.
3. Positioning it after the fact has no affect.
4. The textbox loses focus to the popup and I can't type in it.

Here is my code:

**Javascript**

```
function showPwdHints(x) {
    x.style.background = "yellow";
    $('#popbox').popup('open');
    $('#popbox').position({
        my: "left center",
        at: "right center",
        of: "#pwd"
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<s:password label="New Password" name="NewPwd" class="infoReset" id="pwd" onfocus="showPwdHints(this)"/>
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#popbox" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" data-transition="slide" data-position-to="#pwd" data-dismissible="false">Password Rules</a>
    <div data-role="popup" id="popbox" class="ui-content" data-arrow="l">
          password hints
    </div>
</div>
```

This screenshot shows what it looks like right after I click in the New Password field.  I want the popup to be at the right of the field and the textbox should have the focus so I can start typing and begin real-time validation.
[image]
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you turn your example into a runnable SO snippet please? _(the `<>` button in the editor)_

Comment: It is too complicated.  I can't even get jfiddle to play it.  Here's my jfiddle attempt [link](https://jsfiddle.net/q8whc7ah/)

Comment: I was changing my BankOfAmerica account password the other day and they had this cool pop up as soon as you entered the password textbox.  It had each password rule on a separate line with a red x icon.  As you typed it did real time validation of all the rules.  When one of them was validated, the red x icon changed to a green checkmark icon.  That's what I'm trying to do here ultimately.

Comment: That's an interesting project to try a few things! I would suggest you take some time to look into reactive programming and libraries like Bacon.js. RP patterns are very well suited to this sort of task.

Comment: What is "popup"? Doesn't the plugin have positioning?

Comment: popup is a jquery mobile term.  If you click the button the popbox slides from the right to the center of the #pwd field.  I want it to slide to the right of the field.  If you click in the #pwd field, the screenshot is the result.

Comment: I had to give up on this.  There did not seem to be a way to give the focus back to the text box.  I went with a show/hide div instead. https://jsfiddle.net/tekknow/8qj99bkt/13/